# Magento 2 : 404 page not found to see product after switch store to other store

Tags: magento-2.1, store-view

I got **404 page not found** after I switch English store view to German store view to see product.

> Note : It's display only in 3rd level category page.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

> /vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/etc/frontend/di.xml

Change line no 21 :

```
<plugin disabled="true" name="setStoreSpecificRedirectUrl" type="Magento\UrlRewrite\Block\Plugin\Store\Switcher\SetRedirectUrl"/>
```

I hope it's helpful for you.